# Difficult to understand incomplete gamma function in the solution of 1st order Non-Homogeneous linear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning, gamma-function, calculator, numerical-calculus

I have solved manually this 1st order non-homogeneous linear ODE.$\frac{dy}{dx}+x^2*y(x)=5$

The solution is $\large e^{\frac{-x^3}{3}}*\int5*\large e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}dx$. HP 50g graphing calculator also gives this solution.

But my differential equation solver gives the answer $y(x)=\large e^{-\frac{x^3}{3}}*\large(C_1+\frac{5\sqrt[3]{3}\gamma incomplete(\frac13,-\frac{x^3}{3})}{3}\large)\ldots (1)$

Numerical answer:

(x,y):(-10.0,0.75)

(-7.77777,0.08230539)

(-5.5555,0.1601631122)

(-3.3333,0.428426947)

(-1.1111,2.28138067)

(1.11111,8.053819154)

(3.3333,0.478712609038)

(5.5555,0.16394741)

(7.777777,0.08300819583)

(10.0,0.050100504).

Now suppose i plug in 1.111111 in the solution (1) as x, i must get the y=8.053819154.

But i am not getting this y value.

Note:- My answer to the lower incomplete gamma function is non-real result which is (1.3069748148+2.263746789599i).

When i numerically integrate$\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{1000}{2187}}^0 x^{-\frac23}*e^{-x}dx$, my integral calculator gives the answer 2.61394963.

I want to know where is i am wrong?

Any member may reply to this question, stating the correct answer to this question pointing out where is i am wrong.

Comment: The problem with numerical integration is fixed. Try again. Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, How does my hp 48s calculator give y(x)=8.0538191541189,when $x=\frac{10}{9}$ with initial condition $x=\frac{10}{3},y(x)=0.4787126090380297$. My answer is y(x)=3.1621613877,when $x=\frac{10}{9}$

Comment: What would be value of $C_1$ in the answer?

Comment: You must have some conditions

Comment: My initial condition is $y(\frac{10}{3})=0.47871260903, y(\frac{10}{9})=?$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-\frac{x^3}{3}\right)$$ is real only for $x <0$. A few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-\frac{x^3}{3}\right) \\
 -1.0 & 0.75689 \\
 -0.9 & 0.91312 \\
 -0.8 & 1.08254 \\
 -0.7 & 1.26317 \\
 -0.6 & 1.45290 \\
 -0.5 & 1.64960 \\
 -0.4 & 1.85132 \\
 -0.3 & 2.05631 \\
 -0.2 & 2.26320 \\
 -0.1 & 2.47095 \\
 0.0 & 2.67894 \\
 0.1 & 2.57493 -0.18016\, i \\
 0.2 & 2.47079 -0.36052\, i \\
 0.3 & 2.36622 -0.54164\, i \\
 0.4 & 2.26069 -0.72443\, i \\
 0.5 & 2.15344 -0.91020\, i \\
 0.6 & 2.04345 -1.10071\, i \\
 0.7 & 1.92940 -1.29824\, i \\
 0.8 & 1.80960 -1.50573\, i \\
 0.9 & 1.68185 -1.72700\, i \\
 1.0 & 1.54329 -1.96701\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Concerning

$$\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{1000}{2187}}^0 x^{-\frac23}*e^{-x}\,dx=\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1000}{2187}\right)-\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\approx -1.30697 - 2.26375 \,i$$ which is confirmed using https://www.integral-calculator.com/#

Comment: @Claue Leibovici, My numerical integration answer to this same integral on the same website is 2.61394963. In exact mode, the answer is non-real and when we integrate numerically the answer is real. Why there is a difference in answers?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod. This is effectively a problem that I shall report to the site. Let us see how they react.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod. Have a look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E(-2%2F3)exp(-x)+from+-1000%2F2187+to+0

Comment: How to verify using this value, that when x=1.1111111, y(x)=8.05381915.

Comment: By which name, we call this integral? Is it upper incomplete gamme function or lower incomplete gamma function?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod *the upper incomplete gamma function*

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod. Concerning the online integrator, they already wrote me that there may be some problems when numerical integration involves complex functions.

Answer (score 0):

Computing an integrating factor:$$\mu(x)=e^{\in x^2dx}=e^{x^3/3}$$
so we get
$$e^{x^3/3}y'(x)+e^{x^3/3}x^2y(x)=5e^{x^3/3}$$
Note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^3/3}y(x)\right)=5e^{x^3/3}$$ so we have
$$\int\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^3/3}y(x)\right)dx=\int5e^{x^3/3}dx$$
The first integral gives
$$-\frac{5x\Gamma(1/3;-x^3/3)}{3^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{-x^3}}$$ so our solutions is
$$y(x)=e^{-x^3/3}\left(\frac{-5x\Gamma(1/3;-x^3/3)}{3^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{-x^3}}+C\right)$$
P.s.: Maple gives the following solution:
$$y \left( x \right) ={{\rm e}^{-1/3\,{x}^{3}}}{\it \_C1}+5/9\,{\frac {
\sqrt [3]{3}x \left( 2\,\sqrt {3}\pi-3\,\Gamma \left( 1/3,-1/3\,{x}^{3
} \right) \Gamma \left( 2/3 \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-1/3\,{x}^{3}}}
}{\Gamma \left( 2/3 \right) \sqrt [3]{-{x}^{3}}}}$$

Comment: Graubner, What is the upper and lower integral limit while evaluating $\gamma incomplete (\frac13,-\frac{x^3}{3})$

Comment: It is an indefinite integral, there are no limits

Comment: Graubner, Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: I know this,what is your question? It is the definition of the Gamma-function

Comment: Graubner, My answer include lower incomplete gamma  function, while your maple answer includes upper incomplete gamma function. Now $\Gamma(s,x)=\displaystyle\int_x^\infty t^{(s-1)}*e^{-t} dt$ and $\gamma(s,x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x t^{(s-1)}*e^{-t} dt$. Now in our case, $x=-\frac{1000}{2187}$ which is negative. So how do you define the upper and lower incomplete gamma functions?

Comment: Graubner, How to verify, using your maple answer, that when x=1.111111, y(x)=8.053819154?